# Prove that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ $\leq$ $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose $f,g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Prove that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ $\leq$ $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$.

Okay so I believe I can use either the lower or the upper Riemann integral here to prove the inequality. Can someone help me prove how to do that?

Comment: Start by showing that $f(x)\geq0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int_a^bf(x)\geq0$.

Comment: if $f(x)\geq0$ $\forall$ $x\in[a,b]$ then clearly the lower riemann sum is $\geq0$.

Comment: your problem can be reformulated into the one @GregoryGrant mentions

Comment: Then use linearity once you are done with the steps above, with $\int_a^b g dx - \int_a^b f dx = \int_a^b (g -f) dx \geq 0$

Comment: Follow your idea you can prove that given a partition the lower/upper sum of $f$ is greater than the lower/upper sum of $g$. Since $f,g$ are integrable you got the result.

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19, it seems to me like these hints/comments should give you enough to solve the problem.  Once you have solved it, will you please write up your solution as an answer and "answer your own question"?  This will make sure the question doesn't remain forever in the unanswered queue (plus, it can help you gain a little rep).